# React Website doesn't load fully and glitches

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**UPDATE: This issue seems to only exist when I include the stats component that counts up from zero. When I don't include that, the site loads normally.**

I am working on a website with React.js, but sometimes, when I load the website, the screen starts glitching and it doesn't render properly. I've also attached screenshots of the issue.[image: the white line between the pitctures shouldn't be there]

[image: sometimes the horizontal scroll bar comes up and everything under is blank when I scroll down]

**Here is the website**: https://thetidingsblog.netlify.app/
**here is the sanbox for the component that shows the numbers**: codesandbox.io/s/cold-tdd-u42lu?file=/src/App.js.
**Here is the github for the whole projec**t: github.com/KKosana318/thetidingsblog
The issue sometimes doesn't come up when I first load the site, but if you reload a couple of times, you will see.

Please help!!!

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with CSS, not React. Do you have this on CodeSandbox as it is hard to debug like this? How did you set `box-sizing`?

Comment: Check CSS of the Stats component, just to isolate it as a problem try putting it in a div and later iframe of fixed dimensions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a React issue, because the issue goes away when I remove the component that shows the stats and counts up from zero. I'm not sure how to move the whole project to SandBox but here is the component that shows the numbers: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-tdd-u42lu?file=/src/App.js. Also, here is the github for the whole project: https://github.com/KKosana318/thetidingsblog

Comment: Can't reproduce error with just this but try first removing `width: 100vw`.

Comment: @radulle That fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it, the issue was that the div of the numbers was wider than the parent div, which caused the glitch. The child component cannot override the width of the parent or it messes up the rendering.

Comment: So in fact, it was CSS as I suggested :D